# not able to use easy localization in main file

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, flutter-dependencies

i am using easy_localization pub but when i am adding mentioned lines in main file it is showing error like below -:
[image]

[image]

and i have tried localization pub too but some how it is not working.

please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

For version `v3.0.0` below, it is initialised like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('de', 'DE')],
      path: 'assets/translations', // <-- change patch to your
      fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
      child: MyApp()
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      home: MyHomePage()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but i am getting error as i am not using the latest version because of version conflict in bezier_chart and initl versions

Comment: what version are you on?

Comment: i have written it like easy_localization:  any  bezier_chart: ^1.0.14  intl: any .

Comment: Can you search version of  `easy_localization` it's in pubspec.lock

Comment: yes 2.1.0+0 is used

Comment: Check out the documentation of that particular version https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization/versions/2.1.0+0

Comment: okay i will look in to it.

Comment: after using this also i am getting error as -: Undefined name 'GlobalMaterialLocalizations'. (Documentation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241633/discussion-between-sahil-hariyani-and-palak).